# Databricks SQL converting string value into date format

Tags: databricks-sql

I have a column with date strings all in the same format "`03/22/2022 9:04:25 PM`"

The format that I need them to be in "`yyyy-MM-dd`"

What is an efficient way to write this? I have been googling and trying everything for forever it feels like.

Comment: Better use a real `DateTime` data type, never store DateTime values as Strings